# Maui Numeric Keyboard with flags

Tags: c#, maui

I want to show the softkeyboard with numeric keys and without any spell checks and without suggestions.

```
<Entry Text="" Placeholder="123456" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="entryText" />
```

Then, in the code I can add this:

```
entryText.Keyboard = Keyboard.Create(KeyboardFlags.None);
```

Or this:

```
entryText.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
```

With the second line, I replace the first one. Is there a way to show the numeric keyboard with  some flags?

Edit:
Maui documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-the-keyboard

Edit2:
Here a screenshot of the current keyboard:
[image]

And here what I would like see (numeric keyboard without suggestions):
[image]

Comment: What flags were you wanting to use.  KeyboardFlags appears to be focused on text based input - capitalization, spell checking and auggestions which don't make sense for numeric input. There may be an implied `KeyboardFlags.None`

Comment: When the keyboard opens, I see some suggestions from the last entries. I don't want them as the new number is never the same. So I would like to add the `KeyboardFlags.None` to my keyboard. When I set this with `Keyboard.Create`, I get again the default plain keyboard.

Comment: According to [Customize the keyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-the-keyboard), you may need to set Keyboard="Numeric". Can you help elaborate more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT of course! I updated my post with 2 screenshots. Maybe it is easier to understand. At the moment I can just create a plain keyboard without suggestions or a numeric keyboard with suggestions. But I would like to see a numeric keyboard without suggestions.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks for your response, as you can see [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYGhs.png) when using numeric keyboard, there're no suggestions. You can try to turn off these two settings in [Text correction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYxLf.png).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I believe you. I have some phones to test it and not all phones have the suggestions on the numeric pad. I get the suggestions on the Xiaomi phone. If I create a keyboard with `Keyboard.Create` I can only create a plain keaboard with some flags. I was hoping to see the same function or something similar also for the numeric keyboard.

Comment: @Adriano So it might be related to Xiaomi phone which has the suggestions. You may reach out to the Xiaomi to see if the suggestions can be removed.